# Flutter - Bottom Navigation Bar Icons not updating when selected

Tags: flutter

I have a Navigation bar that I am using for my Flutter app, and while I can properly navigate to the different screens I have set up, the selected icon will not display.

Here is what I have for my Navigation Bar:

```
BottomNavigationBar(
          items: [
            const BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home_filled,
                ),
                label: "Home"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/images/messages.svg",
                ),
                label: "Messages"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/images/notifications.svg",
                ),
                label: "Notifications"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                  "assets/images/settings.svg",
                ),
                label: "Settings")
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: primaryBlue,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          showUnselectedLabels: true,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ),
```

Here is what I have tried:

- Setting `selectedItemColor` and `unselectedItemColor`
  (pictured above).
- Setting color on each specific icon. i.e. `color: selectedIndex == 0 ? color1 : color2`

Here are some other things that I am declaring within the `Widget build`

```
    int _selectedIndex = 0;

    void _onPageChanged(int index) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = index;
      });
    }

    void _onItemTapped(int index) {
      _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
    }
```

Console printing `_selectedIndex` onTap returns the proper index.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Declare variables outside the build method else Variable will get same data on every build(while setState happens). Also update `_selectedIndex` on `_onItemTapped`.

```dart
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onPageChanged(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    // _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables and methods should be outside the build method like this

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final PageController _pageController = PageController();

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      _pageController.jumpToPage(index);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar'),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        children:  const <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.home_filled,
            size: 150,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.message,
            size: 150,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.notifications,
            size: 150,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.settings,
            size: 150,
          ),

        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.home_filled,
              ),
              label: "Home"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.message),
              // icon: SvgPicture.asset(
              //   "assets/images/messages.svg",
              // ),
              label: "Messages"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),

              // icon: SvgPicture.asset(
              //   "assets/images/notifications.svg",
              // ),
              label: "Notifications"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              // icon: SvgPicture.asset(
              //   "assets/images/settings.svg",
              // ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              label: "Settings")
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```